# How to save a spelling to project level directory when using Flutter in Android Studio version 4.0.1?

Tags: flutter

In my project, I have class names that are not actual English words, but are words that I've made up, and they all seem to have squiggly green lines underneath. How do I remove the green lines to tell Flutter that is not an error?

Comment: Flutter is not an IDE. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Android Studio version 4.0.1 - sorry forgot to mention that.